# Image interpolation python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, interpolation, numerical-methods

I have an image with with some amount of lost information (for example, two black lines ). How can I use only proper pixel for interpolate my image? This code interpolate using random pixels. I would gladly take any suggestions

```
   def make_interpolated_image(nsamples):
    """Make an interpolated image from a random selection of pixels.

    Take nsamples random pixels from im and reconstruct the image using
    scipy.interpolate.griddata.

    """

    ix = np.random.randint(im.shape[1], size=nsamples)
    iy = np.random.randint(im.shape[0], size=nsamples)
    samples = im[iy,ix]
    int_im = griddata((iy, ix), samples, (Y, X))
    return int_im

# A meshgrid of pixel coordinates
nx, ny = im.shape[1], im.shape[0]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, nx, 1), np.arange(0, ny, 1))

# Create a figure of nrows x ncols subplots, and orient it appropriately
# for the aspect ratio of the image.
nrows, ncols = 2, 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)
if nx < ny:
    w, h = fig.get_figwidth(), fig.get_figheight()
    fig.set_figwidth(h), fig.set_figheight(w)

# Convert an integer i to coordinates in the ax array
get_indices = lambda i: (i // nrows, i % ncols)

# Sample 100, 1,000, 10,000 and 100,000 points and plot the interpolated
# images in the figure
for i in range(4):
    nsamples = 10**(i+2)
    axes = ax[get_indices(i)]
    axes.imshow(make_interpolated_image(nsamples),
                          cmap=plt.get_cmap('Greys_r'))
    axes.set_xticks([])
    axes.set_yticks([])
    axes.set_title('nsamples = {0:d}'.format(nsamples))
filestem = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_name))[0]
plt.savefig('{0:s}_interp.png'.format(filestem), dpi=100)
```

[For example, I delete part of the information close to the bright circle in the middle of image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ctsD.png)

but to be fair my goal is to get rid of the thin lines that come from the circle. My idea is find this lines, delete it and interpolate using proper pixels. I gues lines comes from circle like

[black something is what I want to get rid of using interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIcZp.png)

Comment: Sample image, please.

Comment: @YvesDaoust add pictures in the question

Comment: I don't understand the image nor what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to use interpolation to get rid of the black spots around the white bright circle in the center using interpolation. @YvesDaoust

Comment: I see "black spots" but they are surrounded by white outlines. I see no circle at all. I don't think it makes sense to "invent" the image in these areas.

Comment: Might be, but this is part of the project and I must find variant to interpolate this  black spots using pixels outside of it . @YvesDaoust

Comment: Fill it with white. Done.